# bootstrap navbar - change from static to fixed dynamically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm a newbie to bootstrap responsive design - I've done a google search but couldn't find an answer.

Is it possible to make a bootstrap navbar static for large screens, but make it fixed to the top for small mobile screens?  I can set it one way or the other, but not choose depending on size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a media query which counteracts the css styling that is applied by bootstrap's `navbar-fixed-top` class at certain sizes.

CSS:

```
@media all and (min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-fixed-top { position:relative; }
}
```

( You may also need to adjust the css of other elements based on your implementation )